# show a rotating menu using jquery - not a typical menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, carousel

I was browsing the web for various catchy ways to show a step-by-step process for a particular section on a web-page when i stumbled upon  [**This Site**](http://www.teamgeek.co.za/#process)  
Developers of this website have created an attractive way to represent "**the way we work**" section 
Going through the source code was not much of help, i want to know if there is any technical term for this kind of effect

(like carousel or rotating menu) and how to create one??

Please note that i want a circular effect like this website
Any reference tutorial website for such similar ways to represent a process would be big help....
thanks!!! (:

Comment: Looks like CSS3 and transitions.  I dont think jQuery is involved.

Comment: any suggestions on how to start for this effect.....? i haven't got any clue!

Comment: http://learn.shayhowe.com/advanced-html-css/transitions-animations

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the source code, they use a JQuery project called roundabout.

For more information: http://fredhq.com/projects/roundabout